# Adding two criterias in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having a little issue here. I was trying to add a criteria for a range of column cells but it doesn't seem to work properly. My case is this : I must add only two digit numbers and also without having them duplicate anywhere in that range. Let the range for example be like A4:A8. I tried this but it doesn't get accepted by the Excel

```
=AND(LEN($A$4)=2,COUNTIF($A$4:$A$8,A4:A8)<2)
```

Can you please advise me on where I am wrong because it's really frustrating to handle.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will add all unique 2 digit numbers in range A4:A8

```
=SUM(IF(LEN(A4:A8)=2,IF(COUNTIF(A4:A8,A4:A8)=1,A4:A8),0))
```

you'll need to enter it as an array formula with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>